# How Can I customize video playback controls on BrightCove player

Tags: ios, brightcove

I am using BrightCove Player for streaming videos in my application, is there any way to customize video controls on BrightCove player?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will want to implement a custom view strategy. The following example is adapted from the [SDK README](https://github.com/brightcove/brightcove-player-sdk-ios#view-strategy):

```
BCOVPlaybackControllerViewStrategy viewStrategy =
        ^(UIView *videoView, id<BCOVPlaybackController> playbackController) {
    UIView *controlsView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    UIView *controlsAndVideoView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [controlsAndVideoView addSubview:videoView];
    [controlsAndVideoView addSubview:controlsView];

    [playbackController addSessionConsumer:controlsView];

    return controlsAndVideoView;
};
```